# How can I download .Net application after creating items container?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm following an Azure Cloud course in LinkedIn learning and I'm trying to get the example application from Azure Cosmos DB, after clicking on creating a container I got always the example application download button disabled.

[image: Click on the first button]
Why I get this?

[image: What I get after clicking on the first button]

Comment: Can you send a link to this course? Want to try to repro.

Comment: https://www.linkedin.com/learning/microsoft-azure-pour-les-developpeurs-developpeuses/employer-les-bases-de-donnees-cosmos-db?

Comment: Ok, took a look. It worked for me but the problem I see here in your screen cap is you have not yet created the items container. You need to do that first before the download button is enabled.

Comment: I have clicked on this button ( create the items container ) but I didn't got the second button enabled , that's was my problem. It still always disabled. see the first cap , it shows that I have clicked on the first button

Comment: Note that I have a free account in Azure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below are the workaround to create a CosmosDb account and add container and download sample project of .net

- Step-1: Create an cosmosDB account in Azure portal.

[image]

- Step-2: Post create you will get like below click on that Create an item .

[image]

- Step-3: After click on that create item go to overview tab make a refresh and the check in quick start you will get something like below to download :

[image]

**NOTE: We can do it on  Azure free trail account as well .**

For more information please find this Microsoft documentation : [Build a .NET console app to manage data in Azure Cosmos DB SQL API account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-api-get-started)

Comment: Yes , I did this but it still give me a disbaled button , I can't understand why I got this???

Comment: Could you please try to create a fresh Cosmos DB Account and check wheather is this the same issue still happens

Comment: Creating new account inform me that "The subscription you have selected already has an account with free tier enabled". so is it normal ?

Comment: Could you please try to delete the old one and create new one. As on free trail only one *CosmosDB* can be created per subscription.

Comment: After creating a new once , I can't really understand what's the problem . it solved now . I will remove all Azure cosmos db subscription , maybe the free tier is the source of this problem

Comment: Did you have any idea how can I remove Azure Cosmos db account?

Comment: Thanks @abdou93, Basically we need to wait few seconds to get things ready so as you have tried many times , So suggest you to create a fresh one and try with my provided steps. To delete cosmos db account please find the [image](https://i.imgur.com/uMuijxy.png)

Comment: The problem is after deleting this account , it still appears in the list and I didn't get another chance to create a free tier account

Comment: Could you please take some time and sign out and sign in again .

Comment: Ok I will try later to sign in , I have already sign out .